# Why did Jennifer lose all her powers just from losing the BFF chain?

Tags: plot-explanation, jennifers-body

In [***Jennifer's Body***](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1131734/), Jennifer became a demon because of sacrificing a non-virgin.

It has nothing to do with her BFF chain, but she loses all her power just by accidentally dropping this chain during the fight with her friend "Needy", why?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> loses all her power just by accidentally dropping this chain during the fight with her friend "Needy"

No! She didn't lose her powers by dropping the chain. Breaking the chain by Needy shocked Jennifer for sometime and gave Needy chance to kill her.

The film tells the story of Needy and her relationship with Jennifer. Needy and Jennifer have been friends forever. As the film progresses it’s clear that both of them have gotten good things from this relationship.

From fandom

> After Jennifer killed Chip(BF of Needy) .Back at Jennifer's house, she was marking her next victim in a yearbook, Needy would later go to Jennifer's home and break into her room, screaming "You killed my boyfriend!" and a fight to the death ensued. As they were both fighting/struggling on Jennifer's bed, she bit Needy in the neck injecting some of her powers into her.
>
> Needy would use the boxcutter and mark an X on Jennifer's stomach which made her mad and fought each other in midair.
>
> ---
>
> *As they were fighting, Needy glared at the BFF necklace that she gave Jennifer when they were kids and took it off her neck, **which shocked Jennifer and gave Needy a chance to kill Jennifer** for killing her boyfriend and stop her reign of terror*.

Answer (score 0):

I believe it was more symbolic than that. Halfway through the movie, Needy finds out that in order to kill a demon you must wait until it's weakest and stab it through the heart. Throughout the movie, the unlikely friendship between Jennifer and Needy is highlighted and a brief discussion about their matching "BFF" necklaces takes place at the start of the film.

By tearing off that very necklace, Jennifer appeared to have lost her power and fall to the bed, giving Needy ample time to stab her through the heart. The point of the necklace-tearing scene was to symbolize how, all this time, Needy herself was Jennifer's heart and was could be rendered weak without her.